# Comparing array items, index out of bound

Tags: java, for-loop, exception

I have a piece of code and I'm a bit confused how to deal with my issue so, please review method below. I was trying to search for a solution but unfortunately none of them fit my needs so I am looking for an advice here. The method is taking a String and removing duplicated characters so for example - input: ABBCDEF should return ABCDEF, but when entering i+1 in the last iteration I got IndexOutOfBound Exception, so I can iterate until string.length-1 but then I loose the last element, what is the SMARTEST solution in your opinion, thanks.

```
public String removeDuplicates(String source){
        if(source.length() < 2){
            return source;
        }

        StringBuilder noDuplicates = new StringBuilder();
        char[] string = source.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < string.length-1; i++){
            if(string[i] != string[i+1]){
                noDuplicates.append(string[i]);
            }
        }
        return noDuplicates.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The most concise solution would probably be `return source.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this like so: append the first character in `source`, and then only append subsequent characters if they are not equal to the previously-appended character.

```
if (source.isEmpty()) {
  return source; // Or "", it doesn't really matter.
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(source.charAt(0));
for (int i = 1; i < source.length(); ++i) {
  char c = source.charAt(i);
  if (c != sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1)) {
    sb.append(c);
  }
}
return sb.toString();
```

But if you wanted to do this more concisely, you could do it with regex:

```
return source.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

Comment: Hi mate. I'm trying to make sure I understand how the regex solution works... `(.)` selects any character into a group, `\\1+` grabs one or more of the character in this group (which are directly adjacent to each other, it won't catch repeating characters not directly next to each other) and then `$1` finds the end of the String it's adjusting and appends the character put in the group (not sure on this interpretation of what it's replacing)?

Comment: "and then $1 finds the end of the String" no, it's just referring to the capture group, that is, the first character is a sequence of repeating characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply append the last character after the loop:

```
public String removeDuplicates(String source){

    ...

    noDuplicates.append(string[string.length - 1]);
    return noDuplicates.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yea but I need another if condition to check if last two letters are not duplicated, because in solution which you suggest we are not checking that. So I cannot just simply append.

Comment: Can you give me an example when it wouldn't work? Your loop already checks the last two and if they are duplicates, it doesn't ever append.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple logic error:
You make your string to a char array.
That is fine, but the length property of any array will show you the
human way of counting if someting is in it.

If there is 1 element the length will be 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
etc.
You get the idea.

So when you go string[i + 1] you go one character to far.
You could just change the abort condition to

```
i < = string.length - 2
```

Or you could write a string iterator, to be able to access the next element, but
that seems like overkill for this example

Comment: The smartest solution would probably be to use the regex expression like @Andy Turner wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove all repeating characters regardless of their position in the given `String` you might want to consider using the `chars()` method which provides a `IntStream` of the chars and that has the `distinct()` method to filter out repeating values. You can then put them back together with a `StringBuilder` like so:

```
public class RemoveDuplicatesTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "ABBCDEFE";
    System.out.println("No Duplicates: " + removeDuplicates(value));
  }
  
  public static String removeDuplicates(String value) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    value.chars().distinct().forEach(c -> result.append((char) c));
    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just what [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) was made for! Under the hood it's a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) with an iterator to keep track of insertion order, so you can remove duplicates by adding to the set, then reconstruct the string with guaranteed ordering.

```
public static String removeDuplicates(String source) {
    Set<String> dupeSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (Character v : source.toCharArray()) {
        dupeSet.add(v.toString());
    }

    return String.join("", dupeSet);
}
```